# Are questions about setting up, or the design of, a system of moderation considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

The question [How do you moderate the moderators?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1/37) Sounds to me more like it's asking how to set up a system of moderation than how to act as a moderator.

Let's say a question like:

> "I have a review queue for moderators to review new posts on my forum. How do I encourage the moderators of my forum to use it?"

Provided it's not about making the UI better, where it would fit into the User Experience site, are questions about setting up, or the design of, a moderation system on-topic here?

Comment: also http://meta.moderators.stackexchange.com/questions/7/should-this-site-cater-to-those-trying-to-build-community-platforms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not? [This meta question](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/how-should-we-approach-questions-about-a-users-rant-against-a-moderation-action) is saying (and rightly so IMO) that we should accept questions on moderator actions from users, so why shouldn't we accept questions from admins and website owners related to moderators? Moderators here can give advice from their personal experiences on how he can proceed to make the experience better for moderators on his website.

Comment: i strongly agree with you and think that building a certain moderation system is also ontopic because it's within the topic of "building" a digital community